# Can anyone help me identify this uniform? Please help!

Tags: italy

I do believe he was part of the Italian military, maybe someone can help me out please.
[image]

Comment: The flag seems to be a horizontal tricolor, not a vertical one like the  Italian flag.  The top stripe is dark, the middle stripe is white, and the bottom stripe is very dark.  The coat of arms does seem to have a cross like the Italian coat of arms.

Comment: Can you provide any other details such as the time period?

Comment: What @SPavel said. Any further information you have about this painting and/or the man depecited in it will help save our users potentially a lot of time figuring out things you already know and ruling out possibilites you already know are off-target.